# Show Toast message in UITableViewController with scroll

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, toast

For the Toast message I am using Toast-Swift in swift 5, Xcode 11
from: [Toast-Swift](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast-Swift)

But I have a problem with UITableViewController, when TableView has scroll, the message is displayed off the screen and the user cannot see the message.

```
// basic usage
self.view.makeToast("This is a piece of toast")
```

I appreciate your help to show the message correctly on screen.
Regards.

Comment: isn't it better to use a UIViewController instead? I had a similar problem but in my case was a button. I solved changing the origin.y value in the viewDidScroll() method but I don't if you cant set a custom frame value in this framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Present the toast in the table view's superview, instead of in the table view itself. If you're using a navigation controller this would be: `self.navigationController?.view.makeToast("This is a piece of toast")` or alternatively you could use the window directly (although I wouldn't recommend this): `self.view.window?.makeToast("This is a piece of toast")`

Also, I highly recommend using a UIViewcontroller instead as UItableViewContoller has that problem self.view == self.tableview and cause this problem with scroll

Comment: Thank you very much, this resolved my problem self.tableView.superview?.makeToast("message")

Comment: @Luis You welcome! If you could make this the right answer :D